# How to use the -U parameter from hg diff command with hg log command

Tags: mercurial

I need to display the output of the `hg log` or `hg export` commands with the full context, as `-U1000` parameter allows when using `hg diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either specify this in your `hgrc` or use `--config` on the command line.
`diff.unified=1000`

For example:

`hg log -r 22 -T {diff()} --config diff.unified=1000`